# Move the rows of 2 tables (with foreign key relation) into another 2 tables (with foreign key relation)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, dml

I have two tables

1. EMP
2. DEPT

The structure of DEPT

| DEPT_ID | DNAME |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | ACCOUNT |
| 20 | ADMIN |

The structure of EMP

| EMP_ID | ENAME | DEPT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JOHN | 10 |
| 2 | VICK | 20 |
| 3 | WILL | 20 |

The other 2 tables, say NEW_EMP and NEW_DEPT also have the similar relation and columns
Here, the NEW_DEPT's dept_id is driven by a sequence  (schema.sequence.nextval)

To migrate the first table, I have done

```
INSERT INTO NEW_DEPT(dept_id, dname) 
(SELECT schema.sequence.nextval, dname||'_'||dept_id FROM DEPT )
```

So, now the data of NEW_DEPT would be: assuming the next val of sequence as 101.

| DEPT_ID | DNAME |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | ACCOUNT_10 |
| 102 | ADMIN_20 |

How can I now relate the NEW_EMP with the NEW_DEPT and insert EMP table rows ?

"Trying to achieve the insert of NEW_EMP"

Result of NEW_EMP

| EMP_ID | ENAME | DEPT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JOHN | 101 |
| 2 | VICK | 102 |
| 3 | WILL | 102 |

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are generating new id's, what's wrong with the old ones? Anyhow, you need to keep track of the relationship between the old and the new id. One way is to create a map table:

```
CREATE TABLE map_dept_id
( dept_id ... not null primary key
, new_dept_id ... not null unique
);
```

Then create the content for this table as:

```
INSERT INTO map_dept_id (dept_id, new_dept_id)
SELECT schema.sequence.nextval, dept_id FROM DEPT;
```

Now you can use this table when migrating your departments as:

```
INSERT INTO new_dept (dept_id, dname)
SELECT m.new_dept_id, d.dname||'_'||m.dept_id
FROM map_dept_id m
JOIN dept d
    ON m.dept_id = d.dept_id
```

Use a similar technique for mapping emp's old dept_id to their new one.

It's usually wise to keep the map table for a period of time before dropping it.

Comment: The reason I am generating new id's in "NEW_" tables is because there might already be data with old ids 
Having a separate table sounds like a plan.
Thanks, will try